# Run Python3 module on Rasberry Pi reboot

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I've dusted off my Raspberry Pi (3 B+) and decided to make a home server using FastAPI.

FastAPI requires Uvicorn to run which is a Python module. Running it looks like so

```sh
python3 -m uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 main:app
```

I would like this to run every time the Pi is powered on, so crontab seemed like the right solution.
using `sudo crontab -e`, I add the line

```
@reboot python3 -m uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 main:app &
```

Online resources show how to execute a **script** where you can specify an absolute path, but not how for a module

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

So just after finishing writing this question it hit me, I need to set the home variable like so

```sh
HOME=/home/pi
@reboot python3 -m uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 main:app &
```

and then it works!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the RasPi docs, setting up a [systemd service](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) is an option as well.

Aside, we use this to run our Flask sites, as well as other background services.

Comment: That is definitely another good solution for more advanced control. Thank you!