# crontab doesnt run python script on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to run a python script automatically when the raspberry pi 4 turns on, and I'm using crontab to do it. The script is a GUI that helps fill and search a database. the raspberry pi doesnt give any errors or exceptions, it just turns on normally and gives no signal of running the script.
the command I used in crontab is:

```
@reboot python3 /home/pi/Desktop/folder/gui.py &
```

the libraries that the script uses are:

- tkinter
- subprocess
- pyserial
- csv

thank you for your time, this is my first time working in the raspberry pi or a linux environment so I dont understand many things about it.

Comment: [Here is another option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66035900/6340496) to consider.  Using a system service, rather than crontab, as this will ensure the appropriate supporting services are already running.

Answer (score 0):

On the Raspberry Pi, the service that your program needs to use may not be activated. In your example, the Display service may not be activated.

Try to do the following:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && python3 /home/pi/Desktop/folder/gui.py &
```

Wait 60s (or more) after the Raspberry Pi starts, which may prevent the code from failing and help solve your problem.

Comment: hi william,thank you for responding but it did not work, the raspberry pi boots up normally, I tried with more time and nothing. Is there another way?

Comment: the display I am using is connected by the GPIO pins, its a touch screen, I dont know if that changes anything.